# Does MPMoviePlayerController download a piece of video before play

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I am in making of a video streaming application. I have a bucket in Singapore where I have stored all my videos. I have got  fair internet speed. I get the Url through the API,

In my android app, I get the Url and start playing it and it starts playing after 10 seconds of buffering while in iOS app, it takes 25 seconds to buffer and then it starts playing.

My Questions is does MPMoviePlayerController starts downloading the video first (for minimum amount) and then play or does it progressively play the content?

Answer (score 0):

It goes both ways.

Normally, yes:

> When a file is delivered over a network or downloaded over the Internet, the entire file is not available immediately, but a typical QuickTime movie can be played while it downloads.

But, it depends on the format of the video file

> It is also possible to create a movie file with the sample data stored first, followed by the movie data structure. This is not usually desirable, because the entire file must download before QuickTime can interpret the sample data.

You can read more of it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Comment: What if I am trying to play MP4?

Comment: Same thing. Maybe try the fix in the test?:
> You can correct this kind of data inversion simply by opening the movie file in QuickTime and saving it as a new, self-contained file. QuickTime stores the movie data structure at the beginning of the file by default.

Comment: Then you are saying if its taking time, then its first downloading the file and then its playing. Is this correct?